# Why _.isEqualWith() doesn't work as expected?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to compare two similar objects omitting `$$hashKey` property.
Why it doesn't work?

```
        var obj1 = {
            class: '',
            kind: 'nats',
            url: 'http://some.valid',
            $$hashKey: 'object:37'
        };

        var obj2 = {
            class: '',
            kind: 'nats',
            url: 'http://some.valid'
        };

        lodash.isEqualWith(obj1, obj2, function (objectValue, otherValue, key) {
            if (key === '$$hashKey') {
                return true;
            }
        });
```

**Note**: I can't use `angular.equals()` for that. Only Lodash or vanilla.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`_.omit()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#omit)

```js
var obj1 = {
  class: '',
  kind: 'nats',
  url: 'http://some.valid',
  $$hashKey: 'object:37'
};

var obj2 = {
  class: '',
  kind: 'nats',
  url: 'http://some.valid'
};

var ommitted = ['$$hashKey']

var result = _.isEqual(
  _.omit(obj1, ommitted),
  _.omit(obj2, ommitted)
);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

@User863 got you the answer with loadash, here is a soluce in plain js :

```js
function checkObjEquality(obj1, obj2, keysToIgnore = []) {
  const keysObj1 = Object.keys(obj1).filter(x => !keysToIgnore.length ||
    !keysToIgnore.includes(x));

  const keysObj2 = Object.keys(obj2).filter(x => !keysToIgnore.length ||
    !keysToIgnore.includes(x));

  // There are not the same number of keyx, the objects can't be equals
  if (keysObj1.length !== keysObj2.length) {
    return false;
  }
  
  // one key of Obj1 doesn't exist in Obj2
  if (keysObj1.some(x => !keysObj2.includes(x))) {
    return false;
  }

  // Check that every key have the same value
  return keysObj1.every(x => obj1[x] === obj2[x]);
}

console.log(checkObjEquality({
  class: '',
  kind: 'nats',
  url: 'http://some.valid',
  $$hashKey: 'object:37'
}, {
  class: '',
  kind: 'nats',
  url: 'http://some.valid',
}, ['$$hashKey']));

console.log(checkObjEquality({
  class: '',
  kind: 'NOPE',
  url: 'http://some.valid',
  $$hashKey: 'object:37'
}, {
  class: '',
  kind: 'nats',
  url: 'http://some.valid',
}, ['$$hashKey']));

console.log(checkObjEquality({
  class: '',
  kind: 'nats',
  url: 'http://some.valid',
  $$hashKey: 'object:37'
}, {
  class: '',
  kind: 'nats',
}, ['$$hashKey']));
```